# F# - Display full results in F# interactive window

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

**Disclaimer:** *Total* F# Newbie question!

If I type the following into an F# file in Visual Studio

```
#light

let squares =
    seq { for x in 1 .. 10 -> x * x }

printf "%A" squares
```

and run F# interactive on it by highlighting and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the output in the interactive window is

```
> 
seq [1; 4; 9; 16; ...]
val squares : seq<int>

>
```

But I want to see the full sequence i.e.

```
> 
seq [1; 4; 9; 16; 25; 36; 49; 64; 81; 100]
val squares : seq<int>

>
```

Is this possible? I'm hoping that there is a setting for this that I've missed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

'seq' is a lazily-evaluated construct; it could be infinite, which is why FSI only shows the first few values.  If you want to see it all, an easy thing to do is convert to a list, e.g.

```
printf "%A" (squares |> Seq.tolist)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, that makes total sense now. Is it possible to ask FSI to evaluate all values in the seq comprehension range (if that's the correct terminology)?

Comment: @Russ, that's effectively what turning it into a List will do...
Otherwise you have to do Seq.iter (printfn "%A") squares

Comment: I notice printfn "%A" [1 .. 2000] only shows the first 100 values. Benjol's solution will print the entire list.

Comment: @Juliet - I thought that's what I saw yesterday when I was playing around. Sounds like iterating over the sequence is the best way to see the value range. I'm sure I'll have more F# questions shortly :)

Comment: @Benjol: sorry to bring up dead horses, but would you mind turning your comment into an answer - it's the solution that would also show results for really long lists (e.g. when the list has more than 100 items)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to display all the values in the sequence without transforming into a List, you can iterate directly on the sequence like so:

```
Seq.iter (printfn "%A") squares
```

Note that you're taking a risk: if, as Brian hints, the sequence is infinite, you could be in for a rather long wait. (In this case, `Seq.skip` and `Seq.take` are your friends)

Comment: On a related note, this 'iter' solution also works when printing large arrays to console in its entirety, i.e. Array.iter (printfn "%A")

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to set `fsi.PrintLength` to a suitably large number, e.g.

```
> fsi.PrintLength <- 500
```

Answer (score 4):

If you get output like `output"+[121 chars]`

```
fsi.PrintWidth <- 500
```

Will make it output more to the console.