# Display full string in F# interactive window

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, f#-interactive, vscode-debugger

If I type the following into an fsx in Visual Studio Code

```
let longString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

and run F# interactive on it by highlighting and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the output in the interactive window is

```
- let longString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepte- ur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";;
val longString : string =
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed "+[384 chars]
```

or as screenshot:

[image: screenshot output]

How can I tell the F# interactive window to display the full string? Is there a shortcut or else?

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1508818/1248177), but as fas as I know this is different here because a string is not lazily-evaluated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printfn`  will print it completely:

```
printfn "%s" longString
```

Alternatively, you can change the `fsi` object properties, for instance:

```
fsi.PrintWidth <- 1000;;
```

Also, you can use `AddPrinter`:

```
fsi.AddPrinter (fun (s:string) -> s)
```

Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-interactive-options#f-interactive-structured-printing

Comment: Yes I know, but I would love to be able to achieve it without changing my code. For example, a change in the config is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, I expanded my answer.

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: the last docs link is broken

Comment: @user1623521 thanks for pointing it out. Link fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just for testing/debugging:
If you are in VSC you can run your script interactively as you mentioned. You can take advantage of that by using the interactive terminal and typing (in said interactive terminal)

```
longString;;

//output
val it : string =
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

This will then show the whole string and is in most cases sufficient (since you do not want to clutter your script with unnecessary outputs anyway).